# Call flask function with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Trying to get some data from a flask function with javascript.
Currently i have a html form and a oninput so I can live update a result when a change occur.

Everything works in the code except the return of  `{{ sentVal(request.args.get('rev'), request.args.get('lang')) }}`. The code works though outside of the  but not inside. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```
<script>
function refreshFunction() {
    document.getElementById("tonality").innerHTML = "Tonality: " + {{ sentVal(request.args.get('rev'), request.args.get('lang')) }};
}
</script>
```

Comment: This does not look like you are "calling a flask function with javascript". You are actually calling a python function from a template which is supposed to generate javascript. Anyway, what do you mean by _"The code works though outside of the but not inside"_?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a [context processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#context-processors), which will make your python `sentVal` function available to your Jinja code.

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def sentVal(rev, lang):
        ...
```

As per comments, if you're wanting to rerun the `sentVal` function, this will need to be converted to an ajax function (there are plenty of easy to find examples of this). But an overview:

In your html:

```
function refreshFunction() {
    var sentVal = // ajax call to your new route

    document.getElementById("tonality").innerHTML = "Tonality: " + sentval;
}
```

and Flask:

```
@app.route('/sentVal'):
   return sentVal(request.args.get('rev'), request.args.get('lang'))
```

This is a pretty basic outline, but hopefully you get the idea!

Comment: Thank you! I am currently using this but I dont think the function is getting called. When replacing it with a string it works but the function does not. I have a submit button and when using it to call sentVal it works.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to re-run `sentVal` when the javascript `refreshFunction` is run? If so, you can't do this. Jinja will be processed when the page is loaded, and not re-run. You'll need to convert this to an ajax call to re-run `sentVal`

Comment: That seem resonable, could I get any guidelines on how to do this?